# Which pronoun belongs to "Atheist"

Tags: pronouns, present-simple

I have an excersise where I have to fill the gap with the verb "believe" in present simple:

> "An atheist ______ in God"

I was thinking the pronoun of an atheist would be "it", causing the result to be: "An atheist does not believes in god". But it's wrong

What pronoun corresponds in this case?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the word "atheist."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An atheist is a person. The pronoun for a person is either "he" or "she" and sometimes the singular "they" is used when we do not know the gender of a person.  In this case, gender is irrelevant, the verb that follows the singular subject  must always be in the 3rd person singular.

The correct answer is in the 3rd person singular in the *negative* form.

> "An atheist **does not** believe in God

Comment: Thanks, I completely unnoticed it should be in negative form...

Comment: To the downvoter, please look at the OP's question, it was edited several hours after I posted. The original said **"An atheist believes in god**, which of course was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

"An atheist" would be 'he' or 'she'.  All singular nouns have the third-person-singular "believes" when they are the subject (though there is a little flexibility when a singular noun refers to a group of things). And all plural nouns have third-person-plural.

However, atheists are people who don't believe in any god!

Answer (score 2):

In all cases, the *first* verb is *conjugated* according to the subject.

> An atheist **believe*s*** in God.

To form a negative sentence we use the helper verb **to do** (in the negative form) and use the *bare infinitive* form of the main verb. The first verb, **to do**, is still conjugated. Note that because the word "do" ends in a vowel, when we conjugate it by adding an "s" to the end we also add an "e."

> An atheist **do*es*** not believe in God.